# Reg: Unreachable Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management

How to get the list of Unreachable objects in javascript before it get removed by garbage collector?

let user = {name: "John"};

user = null;

Is there a way to look at {name: "John"} in javascript?

Comment: no, there is no way. unless you pass the value into another variable before setting the value to null

Comment: If you have a way to get it, then it would no longer be unreachable.

Comment: There is no way to do this from within the runtime environment as defined by JavaScript spec. Some engines might allow it in some way, but it isn't part of the actual spec.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way, an object is garbage collected when it has zero references pointing to it; in other words, when it's inaccessible